# Algorithm - Find active time of resource

Tags: algorithm

I have a resource, let's say a chef that make dishes. I want to know the active time of the chef in the last 20 minutes, the chef can be busy making orders or free waiting for new orders to arrive.

Example of the data that I have:

- order 1: created_at: 12:00, finished_at: 12:05
- order 2: created_at: 12:07, finished_at: 12:11
- order 3: created_at: 12:09, finished_at: 12:15

I want to know the time that the chef was active, in this example, the result should be 13 `((12:05 - 12:00) + (12:15 - 12:07))`

Edit: the created_at and finished_at fields are datetime fields in the database.

Comment: the created_at attribute will always be hh:mm? If that's the case you can just loop through the last 20mins and check if he was busy or not. I don't think that is difficult enough, kindly include all relevant details if that's not the case

Comment: it is a datetime field on the database, i will clarify that!

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss in that case? Is the database being updated live and being queried from the current timestamp or is the database static and given a timestamp we need to find the answer?

Comment: Exactly, i will search for orders that were made from now, to x minutes ago and see the state of the orders that were left, so the data can be assumed static.

Comment: Will you be querying a database for the data or will the data be accessible to the code from the beginning?

Comment: whatever is better, I can get all orders and the calculate in memory

Comment: can the query happen in between a created_at and finished_at? If it does then should I include the current task as well? this would also mean that entries can be made as created_at with the finished_at field empty and to be filled in later.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the datatype of the said database, so I'll assume that it's an array containing series of objects.

```js
dates = [
    {
        created_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 0, 0),
        finished_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 5, 0)
    },
    {
        created_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 7, 0),
        finished_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 11, 0)
    },
    {
        created_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 9, 0),
        finished_at: new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 15, 0)
    }
]

let sum = 0;

// let's say the current time is 12:20
let now = new Date(2020, 3, 30, 12, 20, 0);
// 1200000 is 20 minutes converted to milliseconds
let free_minutes = dates.map(date => (now - date.created_at < 1200000 && now - date.finished_at < 1200000)? (date.finished_at - date.created_at)/1000/60 : 0)
let total_free_minutes = free_minutes.reduce((a, b) => a+b);

console.log(free_minutes, total_free_minutes + ' free minutes last 20 mins')
```

This output returns 10 because there were 10 minutes of free time at last 20 minutes before 12:20.

Although I used the `map` and `reduce` function , you might want to use for loop if you want to increase the readability. Cheers! :)